# a point in dinic's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I don't understand few things in the implementation of dinic's algorithm.

The code given here [Dinic algorithm c++ implementation](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo_cpp/dinic_flow)

why there is a  "work[maxnodes]" array?
  "work" array is used to initialize for loop? why we need an array for that?

could anyone explain to me?
Maybe I missing some tricks.
Thanks in davance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is used for remembering which edge of a node is processed recently, for each node in the graph. That for loop is looping through the remaining unprocessed edges, each time starting the loop from where it left previously.